# Sort duplicates in multiple files

Tags: sorting, unix, duplicates, uniq

I am kind new to programming and I am just starting so please do not think I am just trying to get spoon fed.

I am trying to make one assignment but I am stuck.
the idea is to sort duplicates string among many files.

They are all in one folder.
with 1. txt, 2.txt...n. txt

**1.txt:**

```
hello
hi
world
```

**2. txt**

```
hi
there
hello
```

They all contain different strings. 
I would like to sort them and get result as:

```
2 hello
1 world
```

and so on

I tried this from a bit of searching but no luck.

```
sort file1.txt | uniq -c
```

This mainly does it for one file and I would like to make it for all files at once.

I thank you very much for you're help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd `cat` both files and then sort and count the values:

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -c
```